# A question regarding a minus sign in the derivation of Rutherford's scattering formula

Tags: scattering

In the derivation of Rutherford's scattering formula, for example, this one [here](http://tinyurl.com/qxc6m6k) or this one [here](http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/ab1u06/teaching/phys3002/course/02_rutherford.pdf), we conclude that:
$$\frac{db}{d\theta} < 0,$$ i.e., as the collision parameter increases, the scattering angle decreases.

The thing that bothers me is that the minus sign is merely dropped in what follows. In the first derivation I linked, it says (page 4):

> We omit the minus sign in the following, because it has no physical
> meaning.

And in the second derivation, it says (page 5):

> The minus sign has been dropped as it merely indicates that as b
> increases, the scattering angle decreases - N must be positive.

I understand the reasons... but I just feel extremely uncomfortable dropping the minus sign there, why is it acceptable, why should the "mathematically correct" way give an incorrect result in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These derivations are just being a bit sloppy; they are missing absolute values in certain locations.

For example, in the second derivation there should be an absolute value on the $db$ in equation (2.2.5) because $dN$ is the flux times the area of the ring whose thickness is $|db|$ not $db$.  You can see this by considering the case $db<0$.

If you include the absolute values in the correct places, then it can be shown ([Derivation of differential scattering cross-section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69285/derivation-of-differential-scattering-cross-section/69296#69296)) that the differential scattering cross-section formula becomes
$$
  D(\theta) = \frac{b(\theta)}{\sin\theta}\left|b'(\theta)\right|
$$
where the absolute value on the right hand side takes care of the sign in the correct way.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that makes perfect sense! :)